# Using custom UIImagePicker overlay results in white blank screen camera preview

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am currently using a custom overlay for my camera controls and `UIImagePickerController` with the following set up:

```
self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    //... Additional set up code omitted
    self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
    //!---- If below code deleted and use default ImagePickerController, all works fine
    if (self.imagePickerController.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"overlayView2" owner:self options:nil];
        self.overlayView.frame = self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
        self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
        self.overlayView = nil;

        CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

        float cameraAspectRatio = 4.0 / 4.0;
        float imageWidth = floorf(screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio);
        float scale = ceilf((screenSize.height / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;

        self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);

    }
```

And with the above code, I get the following white camera preview screen:

[image]

However, per the above comments, if I use the default UIImagePickerController, then the preview initiates and works as normally:

[image]

I am unsure which aspects of the setup has resulted in the white blank screen. A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930436/ios-7-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-no-image) on SO asking about a similar issue mentions audio recording, but since I am only focused on pictures, I am unsure how it is related.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you check your overlay view background color, change it to clear color and self.overlayView = nil; looks wrong, do not set them nil here, do it at viewDidUnload as they are view obj

Comment: @Retro `viewDidUnload` was deprecated when iOS 6 came out.

Comment: @Retro can't believe it was a clear color issue.  Thanks!!